# JQuery attr('src') iframe caching issue in IE10 only

Tags: jquery, caching, iframe, attr, internet-explorer-10

IE10 is the only browser that does not refresh an iframe in a gallery.

The iframe is an embed code for an external service, so setting caching meta tags will not work. I tried setting the iframe source to itself (per several forums, iframe.src = iframe.src or equivalent), removing the iframe and reappending it (thought a unique instance of the iframe would refresh).

The only way to get the iframe to refresh is to right-click and select "refresh" in the browser. Has anyone successfully solved this problem?

UPDATE: as an experiment I tried instantiating a new iframe with a completely different external URL in place. This iframe also does not automatically reload and requires a forced refresh. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Just a wild guess: Append something random to the `src` like `www.example.com?1234`

Comment: append a `Math.random()` to url?

Comment: You could try setting the `src` to something that's different; specifically something like `src + '?' + currentTimestamp`

Comment: there are already query parameters on the URL. The thing that changes is after the ?, and when I add another parameter like "&ie10=sucks" it does not work. Thank you all for your contributions, though.